# Memory CLR is allowed to use

Tags: sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, sqlclr

We have been running into an issue where we get this error message when we try to alter a clr assembly in SQL Server:

```
Failed to initialize Common Language Runntime (CLR) due to memory pressure.
This is probably due to memory pressure in the MemToLeave Region of memory.
Error 6513
```

I found information about looking at how much memory the CLR is allowed to use, etc and I came across this query.

Query:

```
select 
single_pages_kb + multi_pages_kb + virtual_memory_committed_kb 
from sys.dm_os_memory_clerks where type = 'MEMORYCLERK_SQLCLR'
```

When I run it I get this:

```
11676 kb or about 11MB
```

Does that mean that the CLR is only allowed to use 11MB of MemToLeave Memory?

Thanks,

S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MS Support KB:

- [Possible causes of "Failed to initialize the Common Language Runtime (CLR)" when using SQL CLR](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2003681)
- Has a link to [Various memory errors are logged to SQL Server error log when using SQL CLR objects](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;969962)
- ... Which has some suggestions for both SQL Server 2005 and 2008